# How to solve my mystery of the Screen stacking segues?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, segue

Quick Question,

Does anyone know if the screen stacking I'm encountering on the Storyboard user interface is going to show up when I run my app?
It happens whether I run a normal perform segue or push/initialize controller functions. I feel maybe this is just a visual way Xcode shows that your screens are segueing but not sure. The current method I'm using is...

```
@IBAction func forumsSegue(_ sender: Any) {
    let theScreen = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChannelViewCon") as? ChannelViewCon
      self.present(theScreen!, animated: true,  completion: nil)
               print("Navigation controller unavailable! Use present method.")
```

What it turns out with in the simulator is a segue to another screen that has this layout...

[Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbqGc.png)

[zoomed view of the stacking screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcIIu.png)

Maybe this will go away when I finally import to an actual device for testing but does anyone know for certain because it happens with any screen switch I to? Thanks.

Comment: iOS13 "new" behavior for modal presentation. Change presentation style to full.

Comment: YES! Okay that was it, just added theScreen?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen and screen is normal. Thanks

Comment: @Larme --Any chance you know of a way to set the default modality to fullscreen for a project?